# Internal Error: Cannot find module '.cache/node/corepack/yarn/1.22.19/bin/yarn.js'

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, hadoop-yarn, corepack

I am getting below error in the Jenkins pipeline. Any idea on how to fix this?

> Internal Error: Cannot find module '.cache/node/corepack/yarn/1.22.19/bin/yarn.js'
> at Function.Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
> at loadMainModule (/tools/nodejs/node-v16.20.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:43987:44)
> at runVersion (/tools/nodejs/node-v16.20.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:44180:10)
> at async executePackageManagerRequest (/tools/nodejs/node-v16.20.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:44824:10)
> at async BinaryCommand.validateAndExecute (/tools/nodejs/node-v16.20.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:42237:22)
> at async Cli.run (/tools/nodejs/node-v16.20.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:43227:18)
> at async main (/tools/nodejs/node-v16.20.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:44863:12)

> ERROR: script returned exit code 1

> GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

> Finished: FAILURE